# Simple way to multiply a column by 100 in a cell array in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have the following cell array in matlab :

```
dataCell = {0.1,0.3,0.5 ; 0.2,0.4,0.6};
```

and would like to multiply the second column ( **[0.3]** and **[0.4]**) by 100. Do you know a simple way to do that without loops?

Thanks a lot,

Sergio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can covert the cell into an array and then back again.

```
result = cell2mat(dataCell);
result(:,2) = result(:,2) * 100;
dataCell = mat2cell(result, [1 1], [1 1 1]);
```

Comment: thanks for your rapid answer.  I think we can even do that in a single line : `dataCell(:,2) = num2cell(cell2mat(dataCell(:,2))*100)`

Answer (score 1):

Use `cellfun()`, though it isn't fundamentally different than a for loop.

```
dataCell = {0.1,0.3,0.5 ; 0.2,0.4,0.6}; 
a = dataCell(:,2);
cellfun(@(x) x*100,a,'un',0)

ans = 

     [30]
     [40]
```

and if you want that placed back in:

```
dataCell(:,2) = ans

dataCell = 

[0.1000]    [30]    [0.5000]
[0.2000]    [40]    [0.6000]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick answer. I knew cellfun but did'nt imagine extracting the second column to use it! I think that I will nevertheless use the second answer in my code (I found a one line answer, derived from @Matt answer below), unless  the conversions between cells and arrays (using cell2mat and num2cell) prove to have problems.

Comment: Makes sense, that's the better answer. Don't know about situations where converting between cells and arrays could cause problems.. seems unlikely, unless there's some efficiency issue